# No "merge to ..." option in DiskGenius resize partition

Tags: partitioning, ext4

I installed DiskGenius PE on my USB drive and tried to resize a partition. As shown in the picture, my `ubuntu-vg(2)` has 463.8GB while its sub-partition `ubuntu-lv` has only 100GB.

[image: Image link, as this website needs 10 reputation to post images]

So I tried to resize `ubuntu-lv` and according to the official website documentation, I should right click on  `ubuntu-lv`, select `resize partition`, click on the drop down menu to the right of `Space of Rear Part`, and replace `Keep Unallocated` with `Merge to ubuntu-lv`. However, I clicked on the dropdown and there was no such option (See the image).

[image: Image link, as this website needs 10 reputation to post images]

I found out that I could just drag the `ubuntu-lv` blue square at the top of the stretch window to fill it up (see the video), but I don't know if that would hurt my data.
[Video link, as this website needs 10 reputation to post videos](https://github.com/Zhou-Shilin/picx-images-hosting/raw/master/20240117/72787034050__ABCA91B7-3CAC-45F8-995B-821939D592DC.MOV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is Linux you can simple open a console, become `root` user and execute following command:

```
lvextend +100GB -r /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-ubuntu-lv
```

This will extend the logical volume and also the filesystem by 100GB

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! For someone who has the same problem, you need to use `sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` after lvextending to increase the size of the filesystem.

Comment: @BaimoQilin, `-r` in the command should do the resize